# Get array value in loop based on redis return

Tags: node.js

Fairly new to using nodejs and redis, but I have a short deadline project and I've run into a little bit of a wall.

I'm writing a script that will register a user when they first log in to our site and open a socket, then will check every n seconds to see if they have a new message populated in redis. If we find it, we will then query redis to get their socket ID and emit the message to them.

I've gotten the registration piece working and right now I'm using an object to try and emit a message, but when I'm looping through the connected users I keep getting the same id, even though there are two. I think it has something to do with nodejs being non-blocking, but I'm not sure where I need to make changes.

Redis looks like the following:

hash: socket_by_user_id
12345, 
45678,

Once the server starts, I have:

```
setInterval(function() { checkForNotifications() }, 5000);
```

And that function (currently) does the following:

```
function checkForNotifications()
{
    redisDB.hkeys('sockets_by_user_id', function(err, keys)
    {
        if (err) return report_error(err);

        for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            var user_id = keys[i];
            //console.log(user_id);

            redisDB.hget("sockets_by_user_id", user_id, function(err, socket_id){
                if (err) return report_error(err);
                console.log(user_id);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When this runs, I'm seeing the following:

```
57905
57905

57905
57905
```

And I'm expecting to see

```
14175
57905

14175
57905
```

which would then also get me the correct socket that I'm going to emit to. Eventually I'll need another call to redis to get the actual message to send, but that's not very useful until I can get this part done.

Comment: It should be `console.log(socket_id);` shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but either that or the user_id are returning the same value, that's just what I had left it at for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to keep your current `user_id` in scope:

```
function checkForNotifications()
{
    redisDB.hkeys('sockets_by_user_id', function(err, keys)
    {
        if (err) return report_error(err);

        for (var i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            (function(user_id){
                redisDB.hget("sockets_by_user_id", user_id, function(err, socket_id){
                    if (err) return report_error(err);
                    console.log(user_id);
                });
            })(keys[i]);
        }
    });
}
```